# Show gaps (diff) between a bar and a line

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot

Is it possible to draw gaps between different chart types?
In my example (picture below) I have bars and a line in the same chart. A gap is always the difference of the line-value and the bar-value below.
Furthermore, if the bar is above the line, it should be a green gap, else a red one.

It's probably possible to draw a "normal" gap-bar from bottom to the line behind the actual bar, but this would only work for the red gaps and not for the green ones?

Here's my example image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLoL3.png

Comment: provide your code for better understanding of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are showing is just 4 different data series.  The blue bar series, the black line series, the green bar "below" series and the red bar "above" series.

Given that you already have a line and bar series like this:

```
var dataBar = [[0,23],[1,34],[2,45],[3,21]];
var dataLine = [[0,13],[1,53],[2,23],[3,90]];
```

You can create the other two series like:

```
  var diffAbove = [];
  var diffBelow = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    if (dataLine[j][1] > dataBar[j][2]) {
      diffAbove.push([j, dataLine[j][3], dataBar[j][4]]);
    } else {
      diffBelow.push([j, dataBar[j][5], dataLine[j][6]]);
    }
  }
```

And then just put it all together using an [array of series](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format) objects:

```
  var dataSeries = [{
      color: 'blue',
      data: dataBar,
      lines: {
        show: false
      },
      bars: {
        show: true,
        align: 'center',
        barWidth: 0.8
      }
    }, {
      color: 'black',
      data: dataLine,
      lines: {
        show: true
      },
      bars: {
        show: false
      }
    }, {
      color: 'red',
      data: diffAbove,
      lines: {
        show: false
      },
      bars: {
        show: true,
        barWidth: 0.5,
        align: 'center'
      }
    }, {
      color: 'green',
      data: diffBelow,
      lines: {
        show: false
      },
      bars: {
        show: true,
        barWidth: 0.5,
        align: 'center'
      }
    }
  ];
```

This produces (example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6cq1LU6EUBIRfI1eyNn3?p=preview)):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know it's possible to provide a start y-value. Easy and the perfect solution!